# Database system that is not relational

Tags: database

What are the other types of database systems out there. I've recently came across couchDB that handles data in a non relational way. It got me thinking about what other models are other people is using.

So, I want to know what other types of data model is out there. (I'm not looking for any specifics, just want to look at how other people are handling data storage, my interest are purely academic)

The ones I already know are:

1. RDBMS (mysql,postgres etc..)
2. Document based approach (couchDB, lotus notes)
3. Key/value pair (BerkeleyDB)

Answer (score 7):

[db4o](http://www.db4o.com)

Quote from the "about" page:

> db4o is the open source object database that enables Java and .NET developers to store and retrieve any application object with only one line of code, eliminating the need to predefine or maintain a separate, rigid data model.

Answer (score 3):

Older non-relational databases:

[Network Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_database)

[Hierarchical Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database)

Both mostly went out of style when relational became feasible.

Comment: I believe both LDAP and the Windows Registry are Hierarchical databases in wide use. If you stretch the definitions a bit, you could also include quite a few file systems.

Answer (score 2):

[Column-oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS) are also a bit of a different animal.  Many of them do support standard relational database SQL though.  These are generally used for data warehouse type applications.

Answer (score 2):

[Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_web) is also a non-relational data storage paradigm.  There are no relations, all metadata is stored in the same way as data, and every entity has potentially its own unique set of attributes.  Open-source projects that implement RDF, a Semantic Web standard, include [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) and [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/about.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't Amazon's [SimpleDB](http://www.amazon.com/gp/browse.html?node=342335011) non-relational?

Answer (score 1):

db4o, as mentioned by Eric, is an [Object-Oriented database management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database) (OODBMS).

Answer (score 1):

There's object-based databases(Gemstore, for example). Google's Big-Table and Amason's Simple Storage I am not sure how you would categorize, but both are map-reduce based.

Comment: BigTable is a column-oriented store.

Answer (score 1):

A non-relational document oriented database we have been looking at is [Apache CouchDB](http://incubator.apache.org/couchdb/).

> Apache CouchDB is a distributed, fault-tolerant and schema-free document-oriented database accessible via a RESTful HTTP/JSON API. Among other features, it provides robust, incremental replication with bi-directional conflict detection and resolution, and is queryable and indexable using a table-oriented view engine with JavaScript acting as the default view definition language.

Our interest was in providing a distributed access user preferences store that would be immune to shape changes to which we could serialize preference objects from Java and access those just as easily with Javascript from a XULRunner based client application.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to detail more on Bill Karwin's answer about semantic web and triplestores, since it's what I am working on at the moment, and I have something to say on it.

The idea behind a triplestore is to store a graph-based database, whose datamodel roots in RDF. With RDF, you describe nodes and associations among nodes (in other words, edges). Data is organized in triples :

```
start node ----relation----> end node
```

(in RDF speech: subject --predicate--> object). With this very simple data model, any data network can be represented by adding more and more triples, provided you give a meaning to nodes and relations.

RDF is very general, and it's a graph-based data model well suited for search criteria looking for all triples with a particular combination of subject, predicate, or object, in any combination. Eventually, through a query language called SPARQL, you can also perform more complex queries, an operation that boils down to a graph isomorphism search onto the graph, both in terms of topology and in terms of node-edge meaning (we'll see this in a moment). SPARQL allows you only SELECT (and similar) queries. No DELETE, no INSERT, no UPDATE. The information you query (e.g. specific nodes you are interested in) are mapped into a table, which is what you get as a result of your query.

Now, topology in itself does not mean a lot. For this, a Schema language has been invented. Actually, more than one, and calling them schema languages is, in some cases, very limitative. The most famous and used today are RDF-Schema, OWL (Lite and Full), and they predate from the obsolete DAML+OIL. The point of these languages is, boiling down stuff, to give a meaning to nodes (by granting them a type, also described as a triple) and to relationships (edges). Also, you can define the "range" and "domain" of these relationships, or said differently what type is the start node and what type is the end node: you can say for example, that the property "numberOfWheels" can be applied only to connect a node of type Vehicle to a non-zero integer value.

```
 ns:MyFiat --rdf:type--> ns:Vehicle
 ns:MyFiat --ns:numberOfWheels-> 4
```

Now, you can use these ontologies in two directions: validation and inference. Validation is not that fancy today, but I've seen instances of use. Inference is what is cool today, because it allows reasoning. Inference basically takes a RDF graph containing a set of triples, takes an ontology, mixes them into a triplestore database which contains an "inference engine" and like magic the inference engine invents triples according to your ontological description. Example: suppose you just store this information in the database

```
ns:MyFiat --ns:numberOfWheels--> 4
```

and nothing else. No type is specified about this node, but the inference engine will add automatically a triple saying that

```
ns:MyFiat --rdf:type--> ns:Vehicle
```

because you said in your ontology that only objects of type Vehicle can be described by a property numberOfWheels.

Conversely, you can use the inference engine to validate your data against the ontology so to refuse not compliant data (sort of like XML-Schema for XML). In this case, you will need both triples to have your data successfully accepted by the triplestore.

Additional characteristics of triplestores are Formulas and Context-aware storage. Formulas are statements (as usual, triples subject predicate object) that describe something hypothetical. I never used Formulas, so I won't go into more details of something I don't know. Context awareness are basically subgraphs: the problem with storing triples is that you don't have anything to say where these triples come from. Suppose you have two dealers that describe the same price of a component. One says that the price is 5.99 and the other 4.99. If you just store both triples into a database, now you don't know anything about who stated each information. There are two ways to solve this problem.

One is reification. Reification means that you store additional triples to describe another triple. It's wasteful, and makes life hell because you have to reify every and each triple you store. The alternative is context-awareness. Having a context-aware storage It's like being able to box a bunch of triples into a container with a label on it (the context identifier). You now can use this identifier as subject for additional statements, hence describing a bunch of triples in a single action.

Answer (score 0):

## 4. Navigational. Includes Tree/Hierarchy and Graph/Network.

File systems, the semantic web, XML, Object databases, CODASYL, and many others all fit into this category.

Those 4 are pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also what is referred to as an "inverted index" or "inverted list" database. Software AG's **Adabas** product would be an example. As with hierachical, these databases continue to be used in large corporate or university environments because of legacy considerations or due to a performance advantage in certain situations (typically high-end transactional applications).

Answer (score 0):

There are BASE systems (Basically Available, Soft State, Eventually consistent) and they work well with simple data models holding vast volumes of data. Google's BigTable, Dojo's Persevere, Amazon's Dynamo, Facebook's Cassandra are some examples.

See [LINK](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1394128)

Answer (score 0):

The illuminate Correlation Database is a new revolutionary non-relational database. The Correlation Database Management Dystem (CDBMS) is data model independent and designed to efficiently handle unplanned, ad hoc queries in an analytical system environment. Unlike relational database management systems or column-oriented databases, a correlation database uses a value-based storage (VBS) architecture in which each unique data value is stored only once and an auto-generated indexing system maintains the context for all values (data is 100% indexed). Queries are performed using natural language instead of SQL (NoSQL).

Learn more at: www.datainnovationsgroup.com